# selecting data from table one table and insert into another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables; `result` and `total`.

```
result(student_code,mark)
total(student_code,total)
```

The `total` column should contain total marks of a student.

So I have written an SQL statement to insert data from result table into total table by using a SELECT statement which should take a specific student_code and his/her marks as a summation and then store it in the `total` table.

But, whenever I try, the query either fails or just takes only one student

When I use this query, it works but for only one student, whose `student_code` is 1, but I need to take all the students and their marks as total

```
<?php

// copy student student_code and summation of his/her mark  from result table into total table
$query = 'INSERT INTO total
(student_code, total)
SELECT  student_code, SUM(mark)
FROM
result
WHERE
student_code = 1';
$sql = mysql_query($query) or (mysql_error());
?>
```

And when I use a student code as a variable I get nothing

```
<?php

// copy student student_code and summation of his/her mark  from result table into total table
$query = 'INSERT INTO total
(student_code, total)
SELECT  student_code, SUM(mark)
FROM
result
WHERE
student_code = "' . $student_code . '"';
$sql = mysql_query($query) or (mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: your not setting the value of `$student_code`

Comment: There's really no need to store this value. And you're using a deprecated API

Answer (score 0):

You must perform two different queries first query selects the data and then store it to a php variable and then later insert it into another table using the second query

UPDATE----

Try this code

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i < 102; $i++)
{
$query = 'INSERT INTO total (student_code, total) SELECT  student_code, SUM(mark) FROM result WHERE student_code = "$i"';
$sql = mysql_query($query) or (mysql_error());
}
?>
```

It must work

Comment: please help me with that, even a hint

Comment: You mean that all the student's marks must be copied from result table to total table

Comment: It is possible but we have to use loops  wait till i post the complete code

Comment: Is the student_code is in a serial number like 4,5,6,7 ....  or in random like 5,9,2,7

Comment: Yes in serial number like 1, 2, 3, 4, up to 101. it is not random

Comment: OK but next time try to right your own code instead of directly asking from others and we are always here to help you with your errors

Comment: thank you very much brother it worked successfully but at the where clause the $i variable should be like this "'. $i .'"